# Must we define $\mathcal A \models (\varphi \wedge \psi)$ using the word "and"?

Tags: logic, model-theory, satisfiability

I'm learning model theory from Kirby's *An Invitation to Model Theory*. In a recursive definition of the interpretation of $L$-formulas, he defines $\mathcal A \models (\varphi \wedge \psi)$ to be true iff $\mathcal A \models \varphi$ and $\mathcal A \models \psi$. This makes sense to me, but I wonder whether we could just define $\mathcal A \models (\varphi \wedge \psi)$ to be true iff $\varphi^{\mathcal A} \wedge \psi^{\mathcal A}$, where the second $\wedge$ occurs in the language in which the model $\mathcal A$ is built, and $\varphi^{\mathcal A}$ and $\psi^{\mathcal A}$ denote the inductive interpretations of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ in $\mathcal A$.

For example, suppose $\varphi = R_1(a, b)$ and $\psi = R_2(c)$, where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are relations in $L$ and $a,b$ and $c$ are constants. Then we understand $\varphi^{\mathcal A}$ to denote the statement $(a^{\mathcal A}, b^{\mathcal A}) \in R_1^{\mathcal A}$, and $\psi^{\mathcal A}$ to denote the statement $c^{\mathcal A} \in R_2^{\mathcal A}$. Then it seems to me that $\varphi^{\mathcal A} \wedge \psi^{\mathcal A}$ makes perfect sense as a sentence within ZFC, which is where the model lives. **Does it, and is this a valid alternative way to define the interpretation of formulas with connectives like $\wedge$ ?**

The main reason I ask is that this brings out a more general confusion I have about what models actually are. The way I currently understand models is as particular sets constructed within first-order ZFC and particular functions and relations on those sets. Since ZFC is a first-order language, it contains sentences with connectives and quantifiers. However, the model theory books I've looked at don't seem to treat models this way—they seem to consider them more like platonic objects that exist without reference to the theory in which they are constructed. So I think answering this question might help clear up some fundamental confusion I have.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: Is the group $S_5$ a particular set constructed within first-order ZFC or a platonic object that exists without reference to the theory in which it is constructed? Ok, a model is that same kind of thing. Are group theory books at fault for treating $S_5$ as a platonic object?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm not accusing group theory or model theory books of anything. Rather, it seems that model theory and mathematical logic address questions where the distinction (between the platonic viewpoint and the formalist viewpoint) might actually matter, and I'm confused about what to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining satisfaction like this isn't wrong, per se -- in fact there's arguably no real distinction between this and the usual way -- but it puts undue emphasis on the formalization of the metatheory.

> The way I currently understand models is as particular sets constructed within first-order ZFC and particular functions and relations on those sets.

This is also not wrong, per se, but it puts undue emphasis on the formalization of the metatheory.

It's better to understand it this way:

> The way I currently understand models is as particular sets <s>constructed within first-order ZFC</s> and particular functions and relations on those sets.

Aside from the fact that we often want to use axioms stronger than ZFC (say, to construct models of ZFC), the point is that models are mathematical structures, on the exact same footing as (say) groups or posets. In fact these are just specific instances of models: a group is the exact same thing as a model of the group axioms, and a poset is the exact same thing as a model of the partial order axioms.

And we don't go around saying

> A poset is a set $P$, constructed within first-order ZFC, and a relation $\le$ on $P$, satisfying transitivity, and so and so.

because "constructed within first-order ZFC" is either redundant, false, or overly restrictive, depending on your foundational stance and particular aims. (If omitting that clause really did commit us to Platonism, nearly every mathematical exposition in existence would be thoroughly committed to Platonism!)

> Rather, it seems that model theory and mathematical logic address questions where the distinction (between the platonic viewpoint and the formalist viewpoint) might actually matter

Perhaps, but it's pretty rare... certainly not worth adding a layer of  formalization to our basic definitions just because at some point we might need to delve into philosophy. We can address that if it actually comes up.

But on the other hand, it's true that model theory can be more inherently set-theoretical than most other branches of math (i.e. running into independence phenomena and conjectures that are tied up with large cardinals with some frequency), so it's not outlandish -- probably prudent, in fact -- to be explicit about the fact that we're working in ZFC. But as with any other subject, including set theory itself, we'll mostly be phrasing our arguments and definitions informally, so why should we write a symbol rather than just (equivalently) saying "and"?

(On a side note, I'd venture to say set theorists get a lot more mileage out of explicitly formalizing model theory in set theory than model theorists.)

Comment: Hi! First of all I have never studied model theory or seriously studied set theory/logic. A question that’s been on my mind is whether or not there is such a thing as a model theory of model theories… you have mentioned ‘undue emphasis’ on the meta theory in your post but to my mind, if we want to rigorously study possible interactions between different models, the effects of new axioms, etc. then we should absolutely keep track of what foundations we are using to argue with. Perhaps things change if we study model theory with a different metatheory; is that studied, at all? It seems important

Comment: It seems important because it seems weird to make arguments about, say, is choice independent of ZF from a metatheory of ZFC (where choice has already been accepted); perhaps the picture changes if you only allow model theory to be formalised in ZF… so is there a theory of what happens, not when you vary the theory which are the models are models of, but when you vary the metatheory with which you study the models? (A model theory of model theory)

Comment: The example with posets, for instance, is resolved by noting any reasonable practical foundational system will be able to support the axioms of a poset and then all usual theory about posets will hold. But, this is admittedly an informal and unrigorous justification. In other places such as category theory (allegedly…) the choice of foundation and formalisation of ‘object’ *can* matter.

Comment: I’d write up an MSE question but it would feel a bit strange, since I never actually have studied model theory and so don’t know what I’m talking about really. If this is a bother then I’ll delete my comments

Comment: @FShrike Yes, I say in the the last paragraph that due to the actual importance of set theoretical issues, we should generally have 'official' (ZFC) foundations when thinking about model theory (though most of what you're concerned with is particular to the use of models in set theory, not to model theory). But that doesn't mean we need to be constantly reminding ourselves of it in places where it isn't actually important, e.g. 'talking in first order logic' when we're giving our basic definitions.

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm still confused on one point: It seems the kind of issue that is "pretty rare" should crop up immediately, with statements like $\mathbb N \models \phi$. Without a formal construction of $\mathbb N$, how am I supposed to know what $\mathbb N$ we're talking about? Model theorists tell me there are nonstandard versions of $\mathbb N$, and even different standard versions in different models of ZFC. So how can any statements like $\mathbb N \models \phi$ be precise without a very precise construction of the model?

Comment: Perhaps the resolution to this is, such claims usually appear where the language for $\phi$ is taken to be PA or something similar, in which we can't form sentences whose truth depends on the construction of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @WillG Repeating the spirit of my comment above: Do you have such concerns when reading, say, an elementary number theory book? When a model theorist talks about $\mathbb{N}$, they mean the same thing that any other mathematician means when they talk about $\mathbb{N}$, namely: the set of natural numbers. And if you a model theorist or a number theorist for an explicit construction of $\mathbb{N}$ in set theory, they'll probably give you equivalent answers (assuming the number theorist knows anything about set theory): the least inductive set, or the set of all finite ordinals.

Comment: @WillG There aren't multiple $\mathbb N$'s in a given fixed background... it's unique, and distinguishable from any nonstandard models of arithmetic that might be around. (Now, you might have models whose natural numbers are nonstandard, i.e. not isomorphic to $\mathbb N,$ but again, no risk of getting those confused with $\mathbb N.$) Likewise, $\mathbb N\models \phi$ is completely precise relative to a fixed background. Now, if we change our background assumptions (say, assume ZFC is consistent), we can change what we can prove true in $\mathbb N,$ but that's no different from anything else.